# tab is not shown when added

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on reactjs with redux to create a dashboard. There is a functionality of creating a tab. I could create a tab and sent to rest api as POST to save it in database however as soon as save button is clicked the tab should also be shown in header which is not showing right now. Also there is a tab name called dashboard(home) which is passed in as initial state which has to be shown all the time. But only saved tab is shown on the header and that is also when user refreshes page not promptly when save button is clicked.

In short the created tab is shown only when user refreshes the page.

Help me to resolve this issue?

**actions**

```
export function addTab(name, icon) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'POST_TAB_START' });
    return axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/rest-api/ui/tabs/',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': CSRF_TOKEN,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: {
        name,
        icon
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'POST_TAB',
                 payload: response.data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'POST_TAB_FAILURE', payload: err });
    });
  };
}

export function fetchTabs() {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.get('/rest-api/ui/tabs/')
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'RECIEVE_TAB', payload: response.data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_TAB_ERROR', payload: err });
    });
  };
}
```

**reducers**

```
const initial = {
  posting: false,
  posted: false,
  tabs: [],
  error: null
};

export const postTab = (state = initial, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'POST_TAB_START':
      return { ...state, posting: false };
    case 'POST_TAB_FAILURE':
      return { ...state, error: action.payload };
    case 'POST_TAB':
      return { ...state, posting: false, posted: true, tabs: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};



const firstState = {
  fetching: false,
  fetched: true,
  tabs: [
          { name: 'dashboard', id: 1, icon: 'dashboard' }
      ],
  error: null,
};

export const fetchTab = (state = firstState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'RECIEVE_TAB':
      return { ...state, fetching: false, fetched: true, tabs: action.payload };
    case 'FETCH_TAB_ERROR':
      return { ...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**tab-dialog.js (here is the form to save tab)**

```
componentWillMount() {
      this.props.fetchIcons();
      this.props.fetchTabs();
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addTab(this.state.name, this.state.icon);
  }

  renderAddTab() { {/* it is for adding tab from the dialog box */}
    const listOfIcon = _.map(this.props.fetchIcon.icons, (icon) => ({
                              text: icon.name,
                              id: icon.id,
                              value: <MenuItem primaryText={icon.name} />
                        }));
    return (
      <div className="device-action">
        <Dialog
            title="Add a Tab"
            modal={false}
            bodyStyle={{ background: '#fff' }}
            contentStyle={customContentStyle}
            actionsContainerStyle={{ background: '#fff' }}
            titleStyle={{ background: '#fff', color: '#1ab394' }}
            open={this.props.createTab.open}
            onRequestClose={this.props.closeTabIcon}
        >
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <div className="tab-name">
        <TextField
          floatingLabelText="Name"
          ref="name"
          floatingLabelStyle={{ color: '#1ab394' }}
          floatingLabelFocusStyle={{ color: '#1db4c2' }}
          underlineStyle={{ borderColor: '#1ab394' }}
          onChange={(name) => { this.setState({ name: name.target.value }); }}
        />
        </div>
        <div className="icon">
        <AutoComplete
          floatingLabelText="select any icon"
          ref="icon"
          filter={AutoComplete.noFilter}
          openOnFocus
          dataSource={listOfIcon}
          textFieldStyle={{ borderColor: '#1ab394' }}
          className="autocomplete"
          onNewRequest={(e) => { this.setState({ icon: e.id }); }}
        />
        </div>
        <button className="btn">Save</button>
        </form>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
  );
  }

  render() {
    const iconSelected = this.props.createTab;
    if (!iconSelected) {
      return (<span />);
    }
    if (iconSelected.id === '1') {
      return (this.renderDeleteTab());
    }
    if (iconSelected.id === '2') {
      return (this.renderAddTab());
    }
}
```

**header.js(here the tab should be shown as soon as tab is created along with the default dashboard tab)**

```
class Header extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
      this.props.fetchTabs();
  }

  render() {
    const tabs = _.map(this.props.fetchTab.tabs, (tab) =>
         <span className="tab" key={tab.id}><a href="">{tab.name}</a></span>
    );

    const navigation = (
      <div className="nav-icon" style={{ margin: '12px 40px 0px 10px' }}>
        <i
          className="material-icons md-23"
          id="1"
          onClick={(event) => this.props.selectTabIcon(event)}
        >
          delete
        </i>
        <i
          className="material-icons md-23"
          id="2"
          onClick={(event) => this.props.selectTabIcon(event)}
        >
          add_circle
        </i>
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar
            title={tabs}
            iconElementRight={navigation}
            onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.props.handleToggle}
            style={{ background: '#fff' }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is overwriting your `tabs` in `fetchTab` state.

```
case 'RECIEVE_TAB':
  return { ...state, fetching: false, fetched: true, tabs: action.payload };
```

This makes it so your `{ name: 'dashboard', id: 1, icon: 'dashboard' }` that you created in `firstState` is overwritten when the `RECIEVE_TAB` action is dispatched.

You probably want to just hard code it into the jsx if it is always there, but you could get it prepended to your dashboard tab by:

```
const dashboardTab = { name: 'dashboard', id: 1, icon: 'dashboard' };

case 'RECIEVE_TAB':
  return { 
    ...state, 
    fetching: false, 
    fetched: true, 
    tabs: [dashboardTab, ...action.payload] 
  };
```

I can't see where in your code you are using the `postTab` state. I'm going to venture that you really just want one state with tabs and when the post to the server is successful you update the same `tab` state that is fetched?

*Edit:*

Your `Header` component is rendering the tabs in the `store.fetchTab.tabs` but when you call the `addTab` function you are dispatching an action that updates a different object in your state, `postTab.tabs`. You probably just want to redesign your state's shape.

*reducers*

```
const dashboard = { name: 'dashboard', id: 1, icon: 'dashboard' };

const initalTabState = {
  tabs: [dashboard],
};

export const tabs = (state = initialTabState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TABS_SET':
      return { 
        ...state,
        tabs: [dashboard, ...action.tabs],
      };
    case 'TABS_ADD':
      return { 
        ...state,
        tabs: [...state.tabs, action.tab],
      };
    case 'TABS_RESET':
      return { 
        ...initalTabState,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const initalTabsPostState = {
  posting: false,
  posted: false,
  error: null,
};

export const tabsPost = (state = initialTabsPostState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TABS_POST_START':
      return { 
        ...initialTabsPostState,
        posting: true,
      };
    case 'TABS_POST_SUCCESS':
      return { 
        ...initialTabsPostState,
        posted: true,
      };
    case 'TABS_POST_FAILURE':
      return { 
        ...initialTabsPostState,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const initialTabsFetchState = {
  fetching: false,
  fetched: true,
  error: null,
};


export const tabsFetch = (state = initialTabsFetchState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TABS_FETCH_START':
      return { 
        ...initialTabsFetchState,
        fetching: true,
      };
    case 'TABS_FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return { 
        ...initialTabsFetchState,
        fetched: true,
      };
    case 'TABS_FETCH_FAILURE':
      return { 
        ...initialTabsFetchState,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

*actions*

```
export function addTab(name, icon) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'TABS_POST_START' });
    return axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/rest-api/ui/tabs/',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': CSRF_TOKEN,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: {
        name,
        icon
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'TABS_POST_SUCCESS' });
      dispatch({ type: 'TABS_ADD', tab: response.data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'TABS_POST_FAILURE', payload: err });
    });
  };
}

export function fetchTabs() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'TABS_FETCH_START' });
    return axios.get('/rest-api/ui/tabs/')
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'TABS_FETCH_SUCCESS' })
        dispatch({ type: 'TABS_SET', tabs: response.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'TABS_FETCH_FAILURE', payload: err });
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution for showing dashboard tab. Regarding tab to show as soon as tab is created, onChange function and onSubmit function is used in tab-dialog.js. I have used fetchTab state to show the tab as soon as user creates it.

Comment: Yes when user post to the server i want to update the same tab and fetch it. For example there would be one tab all for user that is dashboard which cannot be edited or deleted. Now user want to add another tab, for example tab named commercial devices then they will go to add tab and create a tab name called commercial devices and as soon as they post to server the tab commercial should be shown along with dasboard and previous added tabs if there is.

Comment: i understand the post tab reducer and action. But i did not understand tab function. What is the use of that when there is tabsFetch() already ?  Why 2 reducer function are used tab and tabsFetch()?

Comment: I iterated over this.props.tabs.tabs to render tab but i still have to refresh the page to see the tab in header.

Comment: There was a typo in my dispatching the add action. Should have been non plural. `dispatch({ type: 'TABS_ADD', tab: response.data });`

Comment: Fixed that but still has to refresh the page to see tab added in the header

Comment: Is `response.data` from the server a single `tab`? Check to see if the state is updating properly and check to see if the props you are receiving in the Header component is synced with the state.

Comment: i consoled response.data in fetchTabs action and it consoles all the tabs that are in the server.

Comment: I am not that much expert. Can you please give me an idea on how to know "the props you are receiving in the Header component is synced with the state" ?

Comment: It is working now but i am having hard to understand two things. Please why two different reducer(tabs and tabsFetch) are used ? Second if i used tab in tabs: [...state.tabs, action.tab], in tabs reducer the tab is not shown as soon as it is added. Can you please clear my confusion?

Comment: These comments aren't really the place for this kind of tutorial. I'm just going to point you to the docs since they do a good job. http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html